# MySQL return value depending of date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I don't understand why my SQL query doesn't work. I'm trying to do that :

```
if date is null then return 0
if date < 15 min then return 1
if date > 15 min and < 30 min then return 2
if date > 30 min and < 60 min then return 3
if date > 60 min and < 180 min then return 4
if date > 180 min then return 5
```

So here is my SQL query :

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN start_date IS NULL THEN 0
    WHEN start_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) THEN 1
    WHEN start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) THEN 2
    WHEN start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) THEN 3
    WHEN start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 MINUTE) THEN 4
    ELSE 5
END as remaining_time
FROM table
```

But I don't understand why when I got only the cases 0, 1 and 5. remaining_time is never in the. cases 2, 3 ,4.

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such condition will never be met, because the lower bound is greater than the higher bound:

```
start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

You should have the bounds the other way around:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN start_date IS NULL THEN 0
    WHEN start_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) THEN 1
    WHEN start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) THEN 2
    WHEN start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) THEN 3
    WHEN start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 MINUTE) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) THEN 4
    ELSE 5
END as remaining_time
FROM table
```

`CASE` stops on the first matching condition, so this can be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN start_date is NULL THEN 0
    WHEN start_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 15  MINUTE THEN 1
    WHEN start_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 30  MINUTE THEN 2
    WHEN start_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 60  MINUTE THEN 3
    WHEN start_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 180 MINUTE THEN 4
    ELSE 5
END as remaining_time
FROM table
```